# Is it necessary to use texture filtering if I use texture coordinate system?

Tags: textures, coordinates, fragment-shader, uv-mapping, filtering

I have one question about using texture filtering.
It's clear when I used normalized texuture coordinates (in any API) for example from (0,0) to (1,1) it is necessary to use texture filtering because it's not obvious which pixel should be taken for example at point (0.5, 0.5).

But what in case when I use texture coordinate system. For example I use exact pixel position to assign it to fragment in fragment shader, for example (332,543).
Is it necessary to use texture filtering in that case in order to avoid texture artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As more I think about this I found it is always necessary to use texture filtering to avoid texture artifacts. It is because rasterized image which will be textured in fragment shader can have different size of pixels than pixel (texels) in texture.